# How to check if a browser supports focus-visible using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

The question is fairly straightforward. I want to check if the browser supports focus-visible (`:focus-visible`) or not using JavaScript. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log(selectorSupported(":focus-visible"))

function selectorSupported(selector){
  
  var support, link, sheet, doc = document,
      root = doc.documentElement,
      head = root.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],

      impl = doc.implementation || {
              hasFeature: function() {
                  return false;
              }
      },

  link = doc.createElement("style");
  link.type = 'text/css';

  (head || root).insertBefore(link, (head || root).firstChild);

  sheet = link.sheet || link.styleSheet;

  if (!(sheet && selector)) return false;

  support = impl.hasFeature('CSS2', '') ?
  
              function(selector) {
                  try {
                      sheet.insertRule(selector + '{ }', 0);
                      sheet.deleteRule(sheet.cssRules.length - 1);
                  } catch (e) {
                      return false;
                  }
                  return true;
                  
              } : function(selector) {
                
                  sheet.cssText = selector + ' { }';
                  return sheet.cssText.length !== 0 && !(/unknown/i).test(sheet.cssText) && sheet.cssText.indexOf(selector) === 0;
              };
   
  return support(selector);

};
```

all credit to https://gist.github.com/paulirish/441842 from Modernizr.

Answer (score 3):

Every browser that supports `:focus-visible` also supports the `CSS.supports()` API.

So this should work:

```
window.CSS && CSS.supports && CSS.supports("selector(:focus-visible)")
```

Or in ECMAScript 2020:

```
window.CSS?.supports?.("selector(:focus-visible)")
```

Answer (score 0):

js

```
try{document.querySelector(':focus-visible');}catch(e){console.log(':focus-visible not supported');};
```

---

css

```
.class:focus{outline:thin solid red;}/*if :focus-visible not supported*/
.class:focus:not(:focus-visible){outline:0 none;}
.class:focus-visible{outline:thin solid red;}
```